# Exempli Gratia help

Tags: abbreviations, latin

Is there a plural for *e.g.*, the abbreviation of *exempli gratia*?  Or is it regular to use it before multiple examples? I know that some abbreviations double up in their letters in the plural, but I haven't found anything enlightening yet.

Comment: Exempli (of exempli gratia) is already plural, meaning free examples. 
[Source] (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_abbreviate_the_word_'example')
I'm flagging the question because it looks like ready-reference to me.

Comment: @3nafish No, it is not.  That’s genitive singular.

Comment: @tchrist [Here's another page](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Alt/alt.talk.royalty/2007-07/msg00541.html) that says it could be genitive singular or nominative plural.  Can someone who knows Latin verify?

Comment: @3nafish  It makes no sense in nominative. Think about it.

Comment: @TimLymington  I did find one (and only one) reference that uses *exemplorum gratia*, BTW.

Comment: I know latin-- it must be genitive.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The abbreviation *e.g.* is a stock form that is almost never spelled out in English — and shouldn't be. Even if the case markers on the words changed, you would still write *e.g.*

Comment: I confirm, 'exempli' is singular gentive, while 'exemplorum' is plural genitive. @3nafish

Comment: @Robusto: Well, plurals are often abbreviated with double letters, so that would be something to consider, at least in theory.

Comment: English dictionaries define e.g. or eg as meaning 'for example'. It's English. Because it is an abbreviation of the original Latin doesn't make it less so. Pinching words from other languages and assimilating them is usually considered acceptable, as are abbreviations.

Comment: @Cerberus Indeed. As in *mss.* or *pp.*, or *spp.*  In Spanish, the abbreviation for the United States is *EE.UU.*, doubling the letters for the plural.

Comment: @Carlo_R (and Sean and tchrist)  Okay.  I'll accept that the [Answers.com] (http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_abbreviate_the_word_'example') page is incorrect.  Does anyone know how I can remove a flag? There was nothing on it in the FAQs.

Comment: @Cerberus ...so that would give us an electronencephalogram or an egg. :P

Comment: @3nafish I'm unsure what flag you are talking about, however you can ask on the meta site to resolve the problem.

Comment: @3naish: Right! An EEG. As to that Wiki Answer, it is really incorrect. The plural of *exemplum* is *exempla*. The plural of a word on *-um* in the nominative can never be on *-i*.

Comment: This is general reference ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e.g.)), and really just common sense to boot (I haven't even *seen* "e.gg.", "ee.g." or "ee.gg." anywhere, not once, not even as a typo).

Comment: There are more walruses than e.gg.-men.

Answer (score 6):

*Gratia* is the head of the phrase and was originally an ablative singular, as in "for the sake of example". The genitive *exempli* speaks for itself. *Gratia* is commonly said to have developed into a postposition. I do not think you need a plural when describing several examples, because this is about "example" as a concept, not as a concrete entity. I would probably just write *exempli gratia* with any number of examples. In the form *e.g.*, the singular is even less visible, so I would certainly use that with several examples. Note that, whatever you do, you should not pluralise *gratia* in this expression, because it is a fixed postposition.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the rest of your text is in Latin, please do not use *exemplī grātiā* (“for the sake of the/an example”, “for the/an example’s sake”) at all.  Just use *for example* in English.

As far as I know, nobody never writes it in the plural: *exemplōrum grātiā* (“for the sake of the examples”) or *exemplōrum grātiīs* (“for the sakes of the examples”).

Correction: [this](http://www.slideshare.net/snyderw/chapter-vi-summary-presentation)   did, but as you see, the rest of it is already in Latin.

If you are writing English, use *for example*.

Comment: To be fair, OP asks about *e.g.*, which is entirely unexceptionable.

Comment: Am I to assume that the use of all Latin abbreviations are to be avoided?

Comment: @Sean I do not know whether you should assume that “all Latin abbreviations are to be avoided”, but it is my general advice to avoid using Latin in English, yes. It may be the *de-rigeur modus operandi* to lace your writings with *ibid.*, *biz.*, and *op. cit.* when writing articles in academic journals, textbooks, *et cetera*, but it really makes you seem *ipso facto* pretentious to use it in regular text.

Comment: But it's not mine.

Comment: Especially when you've only 600 characters, for example, to play with.

Comment: @Sean: None of the academic journals I edit articles for disallows the use of Latin abbreviations, but some specifically prohibit their _italicization_ (i.e., write "e.g.", not "_e.g._", presumably because they're English now. And some prefer them to be _sans_ punctuation. I'd avoid all but _e.g., i.e., ca., & etc._ Many don't know what _viz._ means. _Op. cit., loc. cit., cf., & ibid._ are usually restricted to footnotes. Regardless, don't overuse them because they're sometimes distracting. And never insert hyphens into foreign phrases: they're set pieces & shouldn't be changed.

Comment: OK, I had an answer ready to go, so I'll post it here.

Comment: I posted on the general subject [here](http://www.vocaboly.com/forums/ftopic6816-15.html) some time ago:

Comment: The question was > how would you "correctly" form the plural of "sauna" in English?

Comment: My answer was: _Sauna_ is nominative singular, and nominative plural is _saunat_.

Comment: Of course, if you pronounce 'sauna' as /sɔnə/ instead of /sauna/, then the plural should be 'saunas' (pronounced /sɔnəz/), since /sɔnə/ is no longer a Finnish word and you couldn't count on the ordinary morphology to work any more. If you're gonna rescue the Classical form, you gotta rescue **all** if it, not just the parts you happen to remember.

Comment: Ditto, by this principle (mutatis mutandis), for all Latin and Greek words; if they're pronounced like they were English words, they get English plurals. If some attempt is made, however, to use original pronunciation (either Classical or Church Latin; Homeric, Attic, or Koine Greek), then one is allowed to use the original nominative plurals (likewise correctly pronounced) in order to demonstrate one's lexical superiority. But you gotta get it right, or no cigar.

Comment: Thus, /detə/ (or /dætə/) is a mass singular noun (with no plural), but /data/ is the plural of the count noun /datum/. Similarly, /ədʒɛndə/ is singular (plural /ədʒɛndəz/), while /agenda/ is the plural of /agendum/ (a useful word, that); and /ələmnay/ is both singular and plural, masculine and feminine, like other beasts of field and forest (exemplorum gratia: deer, salmon, sheep), while /alumni/ is the masculine plural of /alumnus/, and /alumnay/ is the feminine plural of /alumna/. Et cetera, quod libet.

Comment: @JohnLawler: *If you're gonna rescue the Classical form, you gotta rescue all if it, not just the parts you happen to remember.* — What authority do you base this rule on? Most people will disobey and disagree with your rule. Whenever we use a foreign word, we have a choice to use all, some, or no foreign elements. The extreme of "no" (or something beyond "no", you could say) is -icising it to fit the host language, as in Netherlands instead of Nederland(en). This choice is based on various complex conventions. We usually choose the option "some". I don't understand your perspective on this.

Comment: I find it terribly difficult to remember how to inflect and aspect correctly 'A [inuit expression for a polar bear] is attacking me'. All the screaming makes me confuse all the endings.

Comment: @Cerberus: What I meant is that no one can claim that the plural **really** is this or that because of Latin unless they **really** use the Latin. Which is to say that "authority" is the wrong kind of question to be asking. There's really no authority over language, any more than there is over glaciers. All we can do is observe and analyze.

Comment: @Mitch: That reminds me of a story about the linguist Eunice Pike, the sister of Kenneth Pike. Seems she was talking with a group of Australian aborigines whose language she was studying, and one of them suddenly shouted to her "Watch out! There's a snake! Jump east!". The language didn't have bodycentric terms like _left_ and _right_, but used compass directions instead.

Comment: @JohnLawler: All right, but do you really think anyone would make such a claim about language? When the OP asks "what is the plural of e.g.?", he means "what advice can you give me to produce language helping me accomplish y?", where y is probably a combination of social acceptance and aesthetics. Alternatively, you could read it as "what do people in the appropriate peer/desirable group actually use?". Or both; the two usually coincide. But that is too long. Just as "the lizard knows it can eat this berry" is quicker than "the lizard was conditioned by natural selection to crave this berry".